# Why the view don't read the <br> element?

Tags: html, view, yii2

I have this code for the column grid `Descrizione` in my view file:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'Descrizione',
  'format' => 'html',
  'label' => 'Descrizione',
],
```

The problem is that for the field `Descrizione` don't read the `<br>` element. For example, in the database the field is set like `Today is<br>a better day`, meanwhile in the view show the field without `<br>` (`Today is a better day`). I want that the field in the view respect the format when there is a `<br>`. Is already set with 'format' => 'html' but this don't works.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a `<br/>` in that field in the DB? A newline character won't automatically become an HTML break.

Comment: I found the solution. Is the nl2br function. For all, the code is this: 'value' => function ( $model ) {
                return nl2br($model->Descrizione);
              },

Comment: Are you wanting the `<br/>` to be shown as plain text or use it to start a new line?

Comment: To start a new line. I post up the solution.

Comment: **{{ "Today is\na better day"|nl2br }}** you can try it.
for more detail please check reference link: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html

Comment: If your comment solves your problem, then you may post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same with [ntext](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asNtext()-detail)

```php
[
  'attribute' => 'Descrizione',
  'format' => 'ntext',
  'label' => 'Descrizione',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some extra markup to be displayed, you can use this:

```
'format' => 'raw',
```